# binary search on a array with a string prefix

Tags: java, string, binary-search

How can i go about adding the elements of a sorted array which contain a specific string prefix using binary search and those elements as the order they appear in the array to a arraylist..

It is not hard to code but i am having difficulty with binary search. To use the string prefix the String class provides startswith. I just need help to start the binary search

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> ArrayList prefixMatch(T[] list,
            String prefix) {

}
```

Comment: Perhaps your could clarify your question a little... perhaps also add an example of what input and output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i add the method to be completed this not hw sort of a review.. Even though there is generic T[] list the array would be String [] because i have to use binary search to find elements in that array which start with a particular prefix..

Comment: possible duplicate of [implement binary search with string prefix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543046/implement-binary-search-with-string-prefix)

Answer (score 2):

Use the binarySearch method from the API.

```
String[] objString = {"a","b","c"};  
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(objString,"c"));
```

Or if you want to create your own Binary search implementation. Here it is.

```
/* BinarySearch.java */
public class BinarySearch {
        public static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;

        public static int search(int[] arr, int searchValue) {
                int left = 0;
                int right = arr.length - 1;
                return binarySearch(arr, searchValue, left, right);
        }

        private static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int searchValue, int left, int right) {
                if (right < left) {
                        return NOT_FOUND;
                }
                /* 
                int mid = mid = (left + right) / 2;
                There is a bug in the above line;
                Joshua Bloch suggests the following replacement:
                */
                int mid = (left + right) >>> 1;
                if (searchValue > arr[mid]) {
                        return binarySearch(arr, searchValue, mid + 1, right);
                } else if (searchValue < arr[mid]) {
                        return binarySearch(arr, searchValue, left, mid - 1);
                } else {
                        return mid;
                }               
        }
}
public class BinarySearchTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                int[] arr = {1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 5};
                Arrays.sort(arr);
                System.out.println(BinarySearch.search(arr, 2));
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help i really appreciate but i need to implement a binary search for a generic array(string in this case) which is sorted . And then add the elements which startswith or contains a particular prefix to an arraylist inorder as they appear in the original generic array

Comment: The API has `binarySearch(T[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)` method. You could create a comparator and pass it to compare only the prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement - given the array of Strings find indexes of each string which starts with a new letter, i.e. for `Africa Angela Beach Bamboo Zorro`, I needed algorithm which would return `[ 0, 2, 4 ]`

I found that there's a modification of well known Binary Search algorithm which uses 'deferred equality test' and this has the side effect of finding exactly needed indexes - ones which start the range.

You can read about it in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Deferred_detection_of_equality) (also there's a very simple example based on which I implemented my own).